# ModuleNotFoundError in django when adding app

Tags: python-3.x, django

Django can't find my app and it shows me "ModuleNotFoundError" when I try to run server my web

this is my setting.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ......
    'djmoney',
    'transition', --> this is my app 
]
```

and this is the complete error :

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transition'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reason for this error is your project directory structure. If this is indeed the case, you should change it to `xxx.transition`, where xxx = the name of your project.